# my session timeout config don't work correctly in yii 2

Tags: session-cookies, yii2-basic-app

I use this config for manage login duration time of users

```
 'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'enableSession' => true,
        'authTimeout' => 3600*24*120,
        'loginUrl'  => ['user/login']
        //'class' => 'app\components\User',
    ],
    'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
        'timeout' => 3600*24*120,
        'useCookies' => true,
    ],
```

and in login time set duration of login by :

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 3600*24*120);
```

this is getUser() :

```
private $_user = false;

 public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::find()
            ->where(['mobile' => trim($this->mobile)])
            ->andWhere(['not',['status' => User::STATUS['SUSPEND']]])
            ->one();
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

These code work correctly in local , but in server don't work.
I was forced change manually session.gc_maxlifetime value in php.ini for my target. it's work

Question: Why don't work these config in server without change php.ini ? where is the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"?

Comment: @rob006 I mean that user log out after 20-40 minutes , while must user log out after (3600 * 24 * 120 =  120 days) . timeout value does not apply

Comment: Try change sessions directory - there may be other process involved in deleting old sessions.